# appId: error.pattern when create application in Marathon

Tags: docker, containers, mesos, marathon, mesosphere

I'm trying to create an application in Marathon using web console. Here is the JSON file:

```
{
    "id": "TestSpringApplication",
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test /spring-boot-rest-example-0.5.0.war",
    "cpus": 1,
    "mem": 32.0,
    "networks": [ { "mode": "container/bridge" } ],
    "container": {
      "type": "DOCKER",
      "docker": {
        "image": "openjdk:8-jre-alpine"
      },
      "portMappings": [
        { "containerPort": 8090, "hostPort": 8090 }, {"containerPort": 8091, "hostPort": 8091 }],
      "volumes" : [
          {
          "containerPath": "/",
          "mode": "RW",
          "hostPath": "/root/spring-boot-rest-example/target"
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

But when I put it in the box, it appeared this error:

*There was a problem with your configuration*

*appId: error.pattern*

Has anybody face this issue? I has searched so many documents and has not found anything helpful

Answer (score 0):

`AppID` (aka `PathID` must meet certain criteria

> Unique identifier for the pod consisting of a series of names separated by slashes.
> Each name must be at least 1 character and may only contain digits (`0-9`), dashes
> (`-`), dots (`.`), and lowercase letters (`a-z`). The name may not begin

and match

```
^(\/?((\.\.)|(([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9])\.)*([a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9]))?($|\/))+$
```

https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/7523b83799cd4ac0d3ce7ce0392edf77fd84e418/docs/docs/rest-api/public/api/v2/types/stringTypes.raml#L23-L31